# Как удалить класс при клике на событие?

Tags: javascript

**Source:**
[ссылка](https://codepen.io/assylzhan91/pen/bXqyWR?editors=1010)

**Summary:**

```
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
     this.closed();
   });
```

В данном коде не срабатывает событие на отключение **оверлэея**(удаление класса), ну если конечно использовать стрелочную функцию, типа

```
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
         this.closed();
});
```

то все ОК.
Ну мне просто нужно понять, как  это решить без стрелочных функций. Я просто угадал, когда использовал `arrow func` , но есть такие методы `call` или `bind`(я точно не знаю) которые смогут помочь исправить это, *ВОЗМОЖНО Я ОШИБАЮСЬ*.  Хочу докопаться до сути!

Помогите чайнику!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', (function(){
  this.closed();
}).bind(this));
```

или

```
var that = this;
this.overlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
  that.closed();
});
```

Comment: здесь получается переменная that через closure цепляется?? или как...

Comment: @John да, цепляется через closure

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй вот такой вариант.

```
   this.overlay.addEventListener('click', function(){
     this.closed();
   }.bind(this));
```

У тебя теряется контекс. Тебя надо вызвать bind() и оперделить ему    контекст(this).

У стрелочный функции логика работы отличается.Они лексически привязаны к значению this (но не привязаны к собственному this, arguments, super, или new.target).

До появления стрелочных функций, каждая новая функция имела своё значение this (новый объект в случае конструктора, undefined в strict режиме вызова функции, контекст объекта при вызове функции как "метода объекта" и т.д.). Это очень раздражало при использовании объектно-ориентированного стиля программирования.